# Get App purchase price of user in swift

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase

I would like to find out what price a user paid for my app on the app store for downloading it as i would like to show ads to users that downloaded the app for free an hide those ads from those users who paid for something for the app. As I was not able to achieve this in SWIFT with the SKProduct or Transaction receipt requests i was wondering if anybody can help me with an solution for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean people whom got a redeem code (thus the app for free) vs. people whom actually paid for it? I'm not fully following your question. Otherwise the price of the product is on the `SKProduct` class. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2900276/406677 (obj-c example).

Comment: Are you talking about in-app purchase to remove ads? If you don't want to write everything your own then just use this [framework](https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit)

Comment: I want to find out about the purchase price a user paid on the Apple App Store when downloading the app - not an In App Purchase. Eg: I currently sell my app for 99 cents, but sometimes change the price to free. I want to detect those Downloads that have been made for free, to show them ads while leaving out the ads on users that paid. I know i could make a IAP to solve this, but  my app is already out - i dont want to upset those users that already paid. As far as i tried and know i only get localized price for IAP Products and not App Store prices and last receipts show me only purchased IAP

Comment: @Martin were you able to find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can see `answers` for your question under below links, i think will help `you` for `SDK Product`

[Price of in-app purchases shown on screen(with currency)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28905970/price-of-in-app-purchases-shown-on-screenwith-currency)

in

```
import StoreKit

extension SKProduct {

        func localizedPrice() -> String {
            let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
            formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
            formatter.locale = self.priceLocale
            return formatter.stringFromNumber(self.price)!
        }

    }
```

or

Latest `receipt` info you can `get`

[IAPs actually validating the receipt (Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32291701/iaps-actually-validating-the-receipt-swift)

```
if let receiptInfo: NSArray = parseJSON["latest_receipt_info"] as? NSArray {
                       let lastReceipt = receiptInfo.lastObject as! NSDictionary

                        // Get last receipt
                        println("LAST RECEIPT INFORMATION \n",lastReceipt)
}
```

Also

http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-receipt-validation-in-swift/

I think will `help` you.